# Integration not successful in Python QuTiP

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, qutip

I have been trying to use QuTiP to solve a quantum mechanics matrix differential equation (a Lindblad equation). Here is the code:

```
from qutip import *
from matplotlib import *
import numpy as np

hamiltonian = np.array([[215, -104.1, 5.1, -4.3  ,4.7,-15.1 ,-7.8 ],
[-104.1,  220.0, 32.6 ,7.1, 5.4, 8.3, 0.8],
      [ 5.1, 32.6, 0.0, -46.8, 1.0 , -8.1, 5.1],
     [-4.3, 7.1, -46.8, 125.0, -70.7, -14.7, -61.5],
       [ 4.7, 5.4, 1.0, -70.7, 450.0, 89.7, -2.5],
    [-15.1, 8.3, -8.1, -14.7, 89.7, 330.0, 32.7],
     [-7.8, 0.8, 5.1, -61.5,  -2.5, 32.7,  280.0]])
H=Qobj(hamiltonian)
ground=Qobj(np.array([[ 0.0863685 ],
  [ 0.17141713],
  [-0.91780802],
  [-0.33999268],
  [-0.04835763],
  [-0.01859027],
  [-0.05006013]]))

rho0 = ground*ground.dag()
from scipy.constants import *
ktuple=physical_constants['Boltzmann constant in eV/K']
k = ktuple[0]* 8065.6
htuple = physical_constants['Planck constant in eV s'] 
hbar = (htuple[0]* 8065.6)/(2*pi)
gamma=(2*pi)*((k*300)/hbar)*(35/(150*hbar))

L1 = Qobj(np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L2 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L3 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L4 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L5 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L6 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]))
L7 = Qobj(np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]))
#Since our gamma variable cannot be directly applied onto the Lindblad operator, we must multiply it with the collapse operators:

L1=gamma*L1
L2=gamma*L2
L3=gamma*L3
L4=gamma*L4
L5=gamma*L5
L6=gamma*L6
L7=gamma*L7

options = Options(nsteps=100000)

results = mesolve(H, rho0, np.linspace(0.0, 1000, 20),[L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7],[],options=options)
print results
```

This code is supposed to solve the following equation:

[image: Lindblad equation]

where L_i are matrices (in the list: [L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7]), H is the hamiltonian, another matrix, [image: $\rho$] is the density matrix, and [image: $\gamma$] is a constant equal to [image: $2\pi kT/\hbar*E_{R}/(\hbar\omega_{c})$] where T is the temperature, k is the Boltzmann constant, and [image: $\hbar$ = $h/2\pi$], where h is Planck's constant.

Every time I run the code, it gives me the following error:

```
ZVODE--  At T (=R1) and step size H (=R2), the
       corrector convergence failed repeatedly
       or with abs(H) = HMIN
      In above,  R1 =  0.0000000000000D+00   R2 =  0.1202322246215D-36
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/_ode.py:853: UserWarning: zvode: Repeated convergence failures. (Perhaps bad Jacobian supplied or wrong choice of MF o
r tolerances.)
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lindbladqutip.py", line 48, in <module>
    results = mesolve(H, rho0, np.linspace(0.0, 1000, 20),[L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7],[],options=options)
  File "/projects/d6138712-e5f4-4d85-9d4d-77ce0a7b4a61/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qutip/mesolve.py", line 264, in mesolve
    progress_bar)
  File "/projects/d6138712-e5f4-4d85-9d4d-77ce0a7b4a61/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qutip/mesolve.py", line 692, in _mesolve_const
    return _generic_ode_solve(r, rho0, tlist, e_ops, opt, progress_bar)
  File "/projects/d6138712-e5f4-4d85-9d4d-77ce0a7b4a61/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qutip/mesolve.py", line 866, in _generic_ode_solve
    raise Exception("ODE integration error: Try to increase "
Exception: ODE integration error: Try to increase the allowed number of substeps by increasing the nsteps parameter in the Options class.
```

After doing some debugging analysis, it seems like the first or second integration fails. The error tells me to increase the nsteps parameter, which I have tried. Even then it fails. Changing the list of times (the np.linspace function makes the list of times) also has no effect.

I am desperate to know what I can do to fix this error. Please comment if you all need more details.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Have you been through this page from the qutip site?  http://qutip.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2550/doc/2.0.0/html/guide/dynamics/dynamics-master.html  The example they give there seems to closely mirror what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a programming point of view, the problem appears to be your value of `gamma` and therefore the size of your collapse operators.  Print out `gamma` - it is of the order `10**25` - this seems to be what is preventing the solver from converging.

Just for testing (I'm an engineer, not a quantum physicist...), I put in a smaller value of `gamma` (e.g. 0.1), the solver seems to work and gives apparently reasonable output in `results.states`

I don't quite understand your `gamma` - it *seems* to have units of cm<sup>-1</sup>s<sup>-2</sup> as you have set it up.  I wonder if you only want to divide by `hbar` once, maybe.  As I say, I'm not a quantum physicist, so I'm only guessing here based on what makes the programming hang together combined with a bit of dimensional analysis.

***EDIT***

OP indicates in comments that the wrong order of magnitude / units for `gamma` does seem to be the programming issue (i.e. preventing numerical calculus from converging), but isn't totally clear on how to calculate gamma.  At this stage, it may be worth posting a question at either http://physics.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com about that - referencing this one for context if necessary.

***EDIT 2***

I note you asked this [related question on the physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187734/messed-up-units).  This makes it clear where [the expression for gamma comes from](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.0929v2.pdf) and thereby clarifies that the constant terms presented as simply `30` and `150` in this question actually have units (Energy and frequency respectively).  This changes the dimensional analysis - the units of gamma are s<sup>-1</sup> or, with appropriate conversion, cm<sup>-1</sup>.

It also shows the value you mention in comments - 300 cm<sup>-1</sup>.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have realized that the value for gamma should be closer to about 300 cm^-1 but I want a more accurate value. After looking at the equation, it seems that there is no way that the units end up in cm^-1. Could you find a way? Also, gamma should not be square rooted.

Comment: This is obviously a physics problem now. I'm not sure what gamma really represents, or the exact scenario you're trying to model / investigate and it's off topic for this site. For example: I've no idea what the 35 and the 150 represent in your gamma. If the answer put you on the right track in terms of solving the *programming* problem and hinted at the underlying physics problem, could you mark it accepted / vote on it?  I guess you might be trying to get something like eqn 2.5 in this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3911v3.pdf, but anything I do to get a number near 300 would be guess work.

Comment: Of course, as it's a constant, you can just set the value of `gamma` to get you going - check the graphs / states you get out are the right kind of shape and then put in a more exact value once you have got a handle on the correct way to calculate it.

Comment: when I set gamma to about 300, it still givess the same error! any help?

Comment: Start smaller (gamma=1), satisfy yourself the code can work. Increase gamma until it starts to fail. At that point increase nsteps or the convergence tolerance and keup increasing gamma if you can. In patallel, ask about the correct way to calculate gamma elsewhere.